# Geometrically flavored PDE book

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation

As I am interested in Riemannian Geometry, I need to know a good amount of Partial Differential Equation. But just picking up a book on PDE (for example Trudinger) and read it is quite boring for me. Does anybody know a PDE book written for geometric minded readers?

Comment: Arnol'd's book is surely geometrically flavored and certainly not boring. It isn't easy though either.

Comment: Michael Taylor's three volumes on PDE are great, and they contain a lot of geometry. But I wouldn't exactly call them easy to read.

Comment: Is Spivak's Differential Geometry something along the lines of what you're looking for?